# installing orchard 1,7 says file cant be found?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I've just downloaded and installed orchard 1.7,

but when i cleaned and rebuild the project I get a list of errors all referring to `orchard.Tests.Modules\bi\debug\orchard.tests.modules.dll & also the Orchard.Core.dll could not be found...`

using VS 2010, windows 8 64 bit....any idea as to why this is so?

thanks for any replies

Comment: \bi\ ? That looks very suspicious.

Comment: Problem was I had downloaded orchard 1.7 from source control from my colleague (instead of online). It seems when he put the code up onto SVN it didnt put up the DLL files from the test and framework project etc... but these are needed in the actual running. SOLUTION was to download a fresh copy of ORCHARD 1.7.1 from the website, run it, then add existing projects, my modules.